# Where should I post a question about development resources?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for information about when Apple is expected to release the first draft of their Swift Language guide for Swift 3.0. This question doesn't seem belong on Stack Overflow, since it's not directly about programming. It also doesn't belong here on Meta, since it's not about the site. It also doesn't really belong on Super User, since it's a developer question, not a user question.

Is there any site on the Stack Exchange system that's a good fit for this sort of question? It's not a one-off either. Comparing notes about the best references, sharing information about upcoming product releases, etc is useful stuff for developers.

Comment: I don't see how such a question would be useful. An expectation is not something sure - say I post an answer saying "June", but then the draft comes out in December. Also the question loses all its usefulness after the actual release.

Comment: @TZHX, no as [note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: @Qwertiy How is that disputing that this is a duplicate of the question I linked? The answer is "Nowhere."

Comment: @TZHX, as I see, the accepted answer is [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also the question is about tools and libraries, not about specification. If you want to answer "nowhere", seems like you need to post it as an answer here instead of closing as duplicate.

Comment: @Qwertiy No. The accepted answer isn't just "Software Recommendations." It mentions it as a possibility for some small subset, but *starts with saying* that these sorts of questions aren't well suited for SE sites.